# How can I add conditions to yii2 depends in AppAsset class?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

There are some depends in AppAsset class in Yii2:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
];
```

Is there any way to add conditions for this depends like I do it with css and js?

```
public $jsOptions = ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'];
```

Or, may be, you know another way to add conditions to bootstrap and yii JS and CSS files?

Thanks

**UPD:** I've added to config/web.php:

```
'components' => [
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
            'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

But, I've got this (as @arogachev recommends):

```
<script src="/assets/8fd244c6/jquery.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="/assets/bd48c465/yii.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/assets/bd48c465/yii.gridView.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/db9cb9aa/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**UPD2**: answer

```
'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
            'cssOptions'    => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
            'jsOptions'     => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'cssOptions'    => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
            'jsOptions'     => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
        ],
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'jsOptions'     => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
            'cssOptions'    => ['condition' => 'gt IE 7]>'],
        ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize vendor bundles through application config like that:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
                    'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Or in runtime through `assetManager`:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\web\YiiAsset']->jsOptions = ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'];

Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset']->jsOptions = ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'];
```

**Official docs:**

- [Customizing Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles)

Comment: I've added your code to components, but condition has been added only to yii.js asset. Bootstrap and Jquery haven't any conditions(

Comment: Show how you added it, you can update initial question with that information.

Comment: But I don't get what's the reason of adding such comments for these asset bundles.