# Yii 2 - Conditional Assets?

Tags: yii2

We wish to load the following:

```
   <!--[if !IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/good-browsers.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

How can I setup the bundle assets, to conditionally loading a certain css file?

The answer targeted answer this for TWO different resources.

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
                    'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'jsOptions' => ['condition' => 'lt IE 7'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

In this case, however, they both are related to: 'yii\web\YiiAsset'. How can load them conditionally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add conditions to yii2 depends in AppAsset class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892331/how-can-i-add-conditions-to-yii2-depends-in-appasset-class). That said, Yii2 should not ignore your layout - are you sure you don't have cache in place and/or are loading a different layout? Have you checked the source code to make sure that it's being output?

Comment: I'm not reading a different layout. and I have "hard reset" the cache several times now - But, I guess that conditional option will do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: This should not be closed. The linked answer doesn't answer this, I guess.I will reformulate the question.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Please have a look on this question update. It seems that your linked solution doesn't work for this case.

Comment: are you including the _same_ asset multiple times? Why? That said, `AssetBundle->jsOptions` is a public property on the `yii2\web\AssetBundle` class, so you can simply set it up in your app assets. There should be no reason for using the config (and tbh it just makes it look more confusing as you're moving away stuff from where it actually happens)

Comment: @h2ooooooo - I have the assets multiple times, because I need to create a custom CSS file for browsers that are NOT IE. (I need to target IE9 and older ones). On pure HTML I would simply create a conditional rule... So, I need to load two CSS one of them, conditionally. I don't see a better way, unless, I drop the asset bundle usage.

Comment: How about adding two asset bundles, one that is a "generic" one without any `$cssOptions` and one that is an IE one that `$depends` on your base bundle and inlcudes `$cssOptions`, and then simply loading the IE bundle (which in turn should load your base bundle as it `$depends`).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Care to provide that as an answer? I'm totally clueless about the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by creating two asset bundles instead of one and then use the `$cssOptions` property on the IE bundle and have it depend on your generic bundle:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];

    public $js = [
        'js/site.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        '\yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

IE bundle:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppIeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [
        'css/site_ie.css',
    ];

    public $js = [
        'js/site_ie.js',
    ];

    public $cssOptions = [
        'condition' => 'IE',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        '\frontend\assets\AppAsset', // Depend on the regular app bundle
    ];
}
```

Main layout:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 */

AppIeAsset::register($this);

?>

blablabla
```

**Edit**:

I see that you're trying to do it the opposite way - it should still be rather simple as all you have to do is change the name of your IE asset (to not cause confusion) and change the condition.